# Posting to user's facebook timeline through web application

Tags: php, facebook

I am trying to post to a user's facebook timeline through a web application that I am building. Initially I had tried to directly post to the user's wall but it seems that requires user interaction before posting.

Now I am trying to post using custom actions and stories. I have successfully posted to facebook but the problem is that the post on appears on my 'Recent Activity' and that is visible only after scrolling down a lot.

So my question is can I publish to the user's timeline using custom stories?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Custom Story ... Do you mean Open Graph actions ? Yes, you can.

Comment: But why isn't my post visible in my timeline and only visible in the 'Recent Activity' list? What am I doing wrong. Oh also, my facebook application has yet to be approved by facebook but as I am the developer of the application, that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Read [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process). Yes, you need approval first.